# ansible Jinja2 : unicode object' has no attribute 'prefix'

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have following inventory file:

```
172.16.1.177 name=P1
172.16.1.182 name=P2
172.16.1.183 name=P3
172.16.1.184 name=P4
```

following variable file:

```
P1:
 prefix: "16001"
P2:
 prefix: "16002"
P3:
 prefix: "16003"
P4:
 prefix: "16004"
```

Using above if Jinja2 template if I use following this works fine:

```
Host ID for P1 = {{P1.prefix}}
```

and I get output as : Host ID for P1 =  16001

But I want to use this dynamically for each host and when I try following:

```
Host ID for {{name}} = {{name.prefix}}
```

I get following error when running playbook:

```
{"failed": true, "msg": "'unicode object' has no attribute 'prefix'"}
```

Can anyone please help how I avoid this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you typed `name.prefix` you wanted Ansible/Jinja2 to treat the first part (`name`) as a value and the second (`prefix`) as an object name. However `name` too will be treated as the object name.

You can use `vars` dictionary instead:

```
vars[name].prefix
```